# use one jdbc connection class for all classes java

Tags: java

i have been using this JDBC conection in all of my class that had to run query but i created a new class which i dont want the constructor with a parameter of the DConnection from JDBC Class(main Database Class).
but i keep on getting NullPointExceptions. Can anyway figur out what that problem may be.
Thanks.

```
public class UsersDao {

   // associating the Database Connection objekt
    private DConnector connector;

    private final  Connection myConn;
     // Constructor 
    public UsersDao() throws CZeitExceptionHand,SQLException { 
            myConn = connector.getConnenction();
    }
    public boolean updateUsers(String mitarb, int mid) throws SQLException{
        // PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
         Statement stmt = myConn.createStatement();
        try {
         String myStmt = "SELECT Bly "
                        + "" + mid + ";";  
         return stmt.execute(myStmt);

        } finally {
            close(stmt);
        }
    }
```

Example like this Method which is working but in different class

```
String[][] getAllTheWorkers(DConnector connector) throws CZeitExceptionHand {
        try {
            Connection connect = connector.getConnenction();
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT  ");
            result.last();
            int nt = result.getRow();
            result.beforeFirst();

            }
            return results;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new CZeitExceptionHand("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You define your connector varaible here: `private DConnector connector;` but you never inititalize it, therefore it is null when you try to use it here `myConn = connector.getConnenction();`

Comment: how do you mean by init it, because is a objekt that is been called or associated. so i dont know may be give me an example.

Comment: I mean set it equal to something or use the `new` keyword to create a new object. For example: `private DConnector connector = new DConnector();`

Answer (score 0):

The object does not seem to be initialized.
Can you please post which method is not working and from where it is invoked ?

P.S : Unable to add a comment - that is why have answered !

Comment: class UsersDao need connection from Database for all its Methods. but i dont want to implement Database connection in this class because i already have a connection (DConnector ) Class which i used for other class. and now i need to use it in class UsersDao constructor which i keep getting nullpointer.

Comment: Yes in  this case you need to initialize the connection properly. Adding getters and setters for "myConn" should be helpful